# how to make my jhipster entity with one field(singleton style)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, jhipster

I made an entity for my project that holds some system configurations, and want this entity to have only one field i'm thinking that a singleton style would be great but i don't know how i can add it exactly and where since i'm new to jhipster and spring world

i think that if i edit the file 'configuration.model.ts'  ( i mean editing the constructor it might work but i'm still not sure if that's it, here is the constructor.

constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public letter?: string,
    )

i'm expecting to have an entity with one field where i can't add more than it and it shows a message in case of someone tried to add a new field to the entity

Comment: post what you have done so far https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, you speak of one field (one column) and then of singleton (one row). Please edit your question and give more details: JHipster version, database, whether you use JDL, ... I suppose you meant one row and nto one field because end users can't add fields to entities.